# Is going paperless really that much better for the environment

Tags: recycling, paper, defining-sustainability

Say you want to read some document, like an newspaper article,

If you read it online you still have to power a screen, which is powered by a computer or mobile device, which these days are becoming ever more demanding of power as consumers want more

Vs if you read it in the newspaper, which is printed on a thin sheet of low quality paper, sure the paper remains after you read it but you can always recycle it

Does anyone know the enviromonics of paper vs digital, and is going paperless, just a Silicon Valley fad to sell more computers and mobile devices or does it significantly reduce the impact we have on the environment

Thanks